# how to create a view like MeetUp interesting tags view

Tags: android, gridview, android-custom-view, meetup

I have installed the MeetUp application.
In **Your Interests** screen I have found the following view:

[image]

What View is it and how it can be created?

Comment: i think its a RelativLayout with rounded, filled TextViews.

Comment: when adding a subject it inserted automatically to the first available space that has enough room to accommodates it.

Comment: Yes, you be able to do this too. Thinking about margin and padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Meetup app, we have a custom subclass of `TextView` which is heavily based on the [`RecipientEditTextView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/+/jb-dev/chips/src/com/android/ex/chips/RecipientEditTextView.java) from the AOSP [`frameworks/ex/chips`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/chips/).

Answer (score 0):

I have found some libraries on Android Arsenal at -
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/197